# On SonarQube 6.4.0.25310 - Server excluded Issues are not excluded in Sonar Lint

Tags: visual-studio, sonarqube, sonarlint

In our Project we excluded some issues from our project using SonarQube webapication. But after refreshing the setting in VisualStudio2017, and reanalysing the code, the errors still remains. Is this behaviour as designed and/or cann i do some settings to aply the issue-exclusions also in Lint?

Comment: Please edit your question to include your versions of SonarQube, SonarLint, and (for good measure) SonarC#.

Comment: for sure it's a good idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right, SonarLint for Visual Studio cannot hide issues that are acknowledged or marked in SonarQube, yet. We do have this feature in our plans, but I cannot commit to a specific date when it will be delivered.

Comment: Thank you, for the Info.